# Excel: What formula should I use to do conditional formatting for aggregate sum of tasks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To start, I have a table with data on three points. The Quarter, The task name, and how many people would need to work on it in that quarter to complete the task.

Next I have a KEY (on a different tab) that will toggle how many people I will actually have for that quarter.

Lastly, I want to do conditional formatting for the first table. Where (from the top down) Any task that is within the Available Man Hours total for the quarter is highlighted in green (the task name) and anything that is cannot be completed in that quarter is in red. The math would need to be cumulative since each task allocated will take up some of the total resources ...

I had images all prepared, but my reputation is too low to post them. Can anyone help?

**MORE INFORMATION**:

OKAY, I've gotten the simple example to work with the help below. However, I need to expand this with another data point. Let's say instead of having one team, I have many teams. I'd like to add another "team" column to the data points so that I can identify the team, the quarter, the task, and the effort. How would I expand this formula?

Comment: Do you have a number of hours available for each team in each quarter? If so then instead of SUMIF you could use SUMIFS with the team as an additional criteria, e.g. with team in column D `=SUMIFS(C$1:C1,A$1:A1,A1,D$1:D1,D1)<=Hours_for_Team/Quarter` - the last part would need a different calculation than VLOOKUP, if you have a table with Team on one axis and Quarter on the other you can use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If quarters are in column A and hours in C then select column C and use this formula in conditional formatting for green condition

`=SUMIF(A$1:A1,A1,C$1:C1)<=VLOOKUP(A1,table,2,0)`

where table is a two column table in your other worksheet with quarters in col 1 and available hours for that quarter in col 2

This works even if data is unsorted.... and works for the cumulative amounts because the `SUMIF` ranges will expand each row.

For red condition use the same formula except replace **<=** with **>** symbol

see this screenshot - I already applied the green format and some cells are formatted - this is me applying the red format - the remaining cells in B2:B9 will be formatted red once that is applied

see screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Hmm ... I wasn't able to get it to work.  Assuming I have a table header in row one for both sections, and assuming that I instead want to do conditional formatting on the Task Name (text string) and not the effort number ... how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The above works even if you have headers. If you want to format the text string I'm assuming you are still basing that on the numbers in C but you want to format B. You can do exactly the same as above but just select column B before applying the formatting. I'll include a screenshot......

Comment: Okay... my mistake was in the "table" section of the formula. I didn't have things selected correctly. Now that I do. I have the column with the effort formatting correctly, but the column with the task name does not. Using the same formula, it shows all tasks in green, even though the last one should be red.

Comment: OK, I added an example now, I don't know if that helps - is the last effort cell formatted red? Make sure you are applying to the correct range - if your formula refers to A1 and C1 like mine then the "applies to" range must start at row 1

Comment: Aha ... my problem (once again) was that the table didn't have fixed association using the $ signs. So when it was expanding it lost the table location. It's not working. Thank you. I need to expand on this with a more complicated example but this is a great starting point. <p> Actually, let me just ask you. If you had 2 data points for hours (Effort required and effort available) how would you adjust the formula?